# How to split a String array?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

Intention is to take a current line (String that contains commas), replace white space with "" (Trim space) and finally store split String elements into the array.

**Why does not this work?**

```
String[] textLine = currentInputLine.replace("\\s", "").split(",");
```

Comment: Tried, replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","). This seems to work. Is this correct?

Comment: An explanation of what it's doing versus what you expect it to do would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse a CSV file. Be aware that the CSV format is a lot more complex than it appears to be at first glance (due to the complexity of handling metacharacters in values). Should you use a library for doing this?

Comment: @01: That was a stupid edit. Care to explain it? For now, I’m reverting it.

Comment: @Konrad: 01 also added `[beginner]` and `[footer]` to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050284/appropriate-footwear-for-an-interview

Comment: @polygenelubricants: yes, and on several other postings as well. I’m not sure if that’s a troll so I’ve flagged this for the moderators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want replaceAll rather than replace.

And `replaceAll("\\s","")` will remove all spaces, not just the redundant ones.  If that's not what you want, you should try `replaceAll("\\s+","\\s")` or something like that.

Comment: `"\s"` is not a valid Java String. It should be `"\\s"` (same for `"\\s+"`)

Comment: @Carlos - interestingly, that's what I wrote, but because I didn't put it in `code` marks, it showed it as `\s` instead of `\\s`.

Comment: First, you can’t use a regexp in the replacement, only in the search part. Second, this doesn’t remove all whitespace, because it misses common non-ASCII whitespace code points like U+00A0 `NO-BREAK SPACE` due to a Java bug not fixed till Java 7, and even then you have to embed a `"(?U)"` into your pattern to get `\s` to match Unicode whitespace. If you’re used to languages like Perl whose regexes already pick up Unicode by default, it is easy to miss that they do not do so in Java.

Answer (score 10):

#### On regex vs non-regex methods

The [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class has the following methods:

- Non-regex methods:

  - [`String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))
  - [`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
  - [`boolean startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean endsWith(String suffix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))
- Regex methods:

  - [`String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  - [`String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  - [`String[] split(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean matches(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

So here we see the immediate cause of your problem: you're using a regex pattern in a non-regex method. Instead of `replace`, you want to use `replaceAll`.

Other common pitfalls include:

- `split(".")` (when a literal period is meant)
- `matches("pattern")` is a *whole*-string match!

  - There's no `contains("pattern")`; use `matches(".*pattern.*")` instead

---

#### On Guava's `Splitter`

Depending on your need, `String.replaceAll` and `split` combo may do the job adequately. A more specialized tool for this purpose, however, is [`Splitter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from Guava.

Here's an example to show the difference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "  one, two, , five (three sir!) ";

    dump(text.replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","));
    // prints "[one] [two] [] [five(threesir!)] "

    dump(Splitter.on(",").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(text));
    // prints "[one] [two] [five (three sir!)] "
}

static void dump(String... ss) {
    dump(Arrays.asList(ss));
}
static void dump(Iterable<String> ss) {
    for (String s : ss) {
        System.out.printf("[%s] ", s);
    }
    System.out.println();       
}
```

Note that `String.split` can not omit empty strings in the beginning/middle of the returned array. It can omit *trailing* empty strings only. Also note that `replaceAll` may "trim" spaces excessively. You *can* make the regex more complicated, so that it only trims around the delimiter, but the `Splitter` solution is definitely more readable and simpler to use.

Guava also has (among many other wonderful things) a very convenient [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).

```
System.out.println(
    Joiner.on("... ").skipNulls().join("Oh", "My", null, "God")
);
// prints "Oh... My... God"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote does not match the code:

> Intention is to take a current line which contains commas, store trimmed values of all space and store the line into the array.

It seams, by the code, that you want all spaces removed and split the resulting string at the commas (not described). That can be done as Paul Tomblin suggested.

```
String[] currentLineArray = currentInputLine.replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");
```

If you want to split at the commas and remove leading and trailing spaces (trim) from the resulting parts, use:

```
String[] currentLineArray = currentInputLine.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

(`trim()` is needed to remove leading spaces of first *part* and trailing space from last *part*)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform this operation repeatedly, I'd suggest using `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher` instead.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regex);
for(String inp: inps) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( inpString);
    return matcher.replaceAll( replacementString); 
}
```

Compiling a regex is a costly operation and using String's replaceAll repeatedly is not recommended, since each invocation involves compilation of regex followed by replacement.