# Java - Regex for the given string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following html code segment:

```
        <br>
        Date: 2010-06-20,  1:37AM PDT<br>
        <br>
        Daddy: <a href="...">www.google.com</a>
        <br>
```

I want to extract

`Date: 2010-06-20,  1:37AM PDT`

and

`Daddy: <a href="...">www.google.com</a>`

with the help of java regex.

So what regex I should use?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job. However, you need to provide a bit more context before we can give a more suitable answer. Where does this HTML come from? How are you loading it? How does the complete HTML look like? Do you have control over it?

Comment: @BalusC - A `.split()` with regex may be pretty straightforward here though, just whitespace and `<br>`, just a thought.

Comment: @Nick: not if there's more into the *actual* HTML than only this "segment".

Comment: @BalusC - Agreed, hopefully that's not the case and he has this exact string already.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a nice starting point:

```
    String text = 
    "        <br>\n" +
    "        Date: 2010-06-20,  1:37AM PDT<br>   \n" +
    "   <br>    \n" +
    "Daddy: <a href=\"...\">www.google.com</a>   \n" +
    "<br>";

    String[] parts = text.split("(?:\\s*<br>\\s*)+");
    for (String part : parts) {
        System.out.println("[" + part + "]");
    }
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/hY685)):

```
[]
[Date: 2010-06-20,  1:37AM PDT]
[Daddy: <a href="...">www.google.com</a>]
```

This uses [`String[] String.split(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). The regex pattern is "one or more of `<br>`, with preceding or trailing whitespaces.

---

#### Guava alternative

You can also use [`Splitter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from Guava. It's actually a lot more readable, and can `omitEmptyStrings()`.

```
    Splitter splitter = Splitter.on("<br>").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();
    for (String part : splitter.split(text)) {
        System.out.println("[" + part + "]");
    }
```

This prints:

```
[Date: 2010-06-20,  1:37AM PDT]
[Daddy: <a href="...">www.google.com</a>]
```

#### Related questions

- [String split array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034757/string-split-array)

Comment: Also maybe you want something like this? http://www.rubular.com/r/wy3b1ABsaC Leave a comment and I'll elaborate on any of these approaches.

Comment: Also check this one out: http://www.rubular.com/r/mftjWgKWzP Tell me which one you fancy.

Comment: I agree. For this kind of html, you shouldn't use regex, instead, you have the key which is tag "br".